# How to run binaries compiled with "aarch64-arm-none-eabi" on target linux os compiled with "aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc"

Tags: c, compiler-errors, segmentation-fault, arm, arm64

I have linux running on aarch64 platform. I want to run binary compiled with aarch64-arm-none-eabi but after executing, it gives error "segmentation error".
Any idea how to resolve it?

Comment: Generally, the compiler should not matter, what matters is the environment (the binaries don't exist in vacuum) - libc, kernel, hardware - what is there, and what is expected from the compiled binary?

Comment: Can you try strace on the binary that you are trying execute? BR
Subbu